# Integers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, floating-point, integer

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript#Numbers) states:

> Numbers in JavaScript are
> "double-precision 64-bit format IEEE
> 754 values", according to the spec.
> This has some interesting
> consequences. **There's no such thing as
> an integer in JavaScript**, so you have
> to be a little careful with your
> arithmetic if you're used to math in C
> or Java.

This suggests all numbers are `float`s. Is there any way to use `int`egers, not `float`?

Comment: MDN is a great resource and is frequently referenced here at SO.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are really only a few data types in Javascript: Objects, numbers, and strings.  As you read, JS numbers are all 64-bit floats.  There are no ints.

Firefox 4 will have support for Typed Arrays, where you can have arrays of *real* ints and such: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays

Until then, there are hackish ways to store integer arrays as strings, and plucking out each integers using `charCodeAt()`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it ever will support integers. It isn't a problem as every unsigned 32 bit integer can be accurately represented as a 64 bit floating point number.

Modern JavaScript engines could be smart enough to generate special code when the numbers are integer (with safeguard checks to make sure of it), but I'm not sure.

Comment: All JS engines (SpiderMonkey's has from its very first implementation — the first JS engine) have used int32-maths when possible.

Comment: It isn't a problem... until you want a 64-bit int or larger.

Comment: well, it can be a quite big problem actually. If you send 100000 integers to javascript and asks it to summarize, the floating point problems might give you quite strange answers. That is why I found this question.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
function int(a) { return Math.floor(a); }
```

And yo can use it like this:

```
var result = int(2.1 + 8.7 + 9.3); //int(20.1)
alert(result);                     //alerts 20
```

Comment: Is there any point at all in this other than creating a slightly alias of `Math.floor`?

Comment: I would use `var int = Math.floor;` to avoid the extra function call.

Comment: Is there any reason not to just do `(a | 0)`?

Comment: @MikeSamuel, binary bitwise operations convert operands to 32bit integers, so bits 32-51 would be lost.

Comment: @Valentin, Loss of precision is important, but the question asked about "C++ `int`s" which only have 32b on many widely-used architectures so it's not clear that there is a loss of precision from the askers point of view.

Answer (score 0):

There is zero support for integers. It should be a simple matter of rounding off a variable every time you need it. The performance overhead isn't bad at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use integers, just use the floor method on each number you encounter.

Other than that, the loose typing of Javascript is one of it's strengths.