# Base 10 to Base 32 Conversion

Tags: delphi, base-conversion

I have a routine that converts base10 to bas32 and what is interesting that when I double check some numbers using online conversion tools there seems to be an issue. Here are some numbers and the results of my conversion:

```
9990330227991015 = 8RU4S26R8F7
9990330227991016 = 8RU4S26R8F8
9990330227991017 = 8RU4S26R8F9
```

However, all 3 numbers using several online tools (such as http://www.unitconversion.org/numbers/base-10-to-base-32-conversion.html and http://www.kaagaard.dk/service/convert.htm) return 8RU4S26R8F8. I thought it might be the numbers length but the conversions do change if you go higher or lower.

Any ideas why this should be?

Comment: If three different numbers in base10 convert to the same number in base 32, there's a bug in the converter.  Not seeing the code for either these online tools or yours, there's little more to say.

Comment: Do you think **your** converter is wrong, or would you like help with debugging the javascript-baed implementation on some 3rd party site?

Comment: If all you want is double-check your algorithm, use numbers that can be safely represented using a 32 bit signed integer: 8 digits, and if'ts 9 digits better start with a 1 as 2 is not all that safe.

Comment: no I wasn't concerned about my algorithm just wondered as to the reason teh others were incorrect as it was also an issue in some other software at our clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the general consensus is that the online tools that I looked at are probably using real numbers rather than Int64. Using floating point numbers gives the incorrect results illustrated above.

Comment: That makes sense. The online tools are using JavaScript, and [there are no ints in that language](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4703725/33732).

Comment: But there should be BCD or text-numbers for JS ?

Answer (score 3):

It is funny that I have just found this post as I have just investigated this issue with the exact same numbers for our software developed in Delphi as a client was receiving the below after using our conversion tool:-

```
9990330227991015 = 8RU4S26R8F8
9990330227991016 = 8RU4S26R8F8
9990330227991017 = 8RU4S26R8F8
```

The online tools you refer to are incorrect for the same reason as our tool is incorrect, basically don't use a floating point, use a 64bit integer to handle large numbers more accurately..

A fix is about to be delivered to our Client...

Comment: You got me curious. The basic algorithm for converting from base-to-base requires integer division and using the remainder as the next digit in the target base. How did you end up with a floating-point based algorithm? Any chance you used the `real` Delphi type? Because that's only 48 bits long, it probably can't represent the whole number, so it probably got truncated from the start.

Comment: My application did the correct calculation - my routine uses Int64 - I was just curious that some of the online tools (and some other apps at our client - I wonder if it is the same one :-)) made the above error and thought it worth mentioning.