# Javascript/jquery complex addition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please refer below code.

```
    currentAxis.Range.Start = 1956.9

    tempInterval = currentAxis.Range.Start

    currentAxis.Range.Interval = 0.4

    tempInterval += currentAxis.Range.Interval;
```

It will return the value  `1957.3000000000001` instead of `1957.3`. I don't want to use the `toFixed()` method to remove the decimal values in point, because some times the interval value will be `0.0004`  that time it will return 4 digits after the point. Based on the interval it will vary.

I need `1956.9 +0.4= 1957.3`  with out using `toFixed()` method. How can i solve this?

Comment: Does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342957/how-do-you-round-to-1-decimal-place-in-javascript) help you?

Comment: no. if am adding single digit point value , the output also will contains same .like "0.4" is single digit so it will add with X and returns "19.X" single digit after the point. no need "toFixed(x) or some calculation ? why this problem occurs in javascript

Comment: Floating point standards bear that much of rounding error... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: That's javascript. Numerical accuracy is not guaranteed.

Comment: That's not a JavaScript problem, that's how floating point arithmetic works. If you don't want to perform any computation, then there is no way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try Multiply by 10, fix to decimal & divide by 10.

Using :

```
Math.round((1956.9 +0.4)*10)/10           // Output 1957.3
```

or simply :

```
(((1956.9 + 0.4)*10)<<0)/10               // Output 1957.3
```

Comment: i dont want to perform calculation. because (1956.9 +0.0004) it will return 4 digits after the point. based on the values we are going to add with "X" it will vary. no need to use"toFixed(x) or some manual calculation ? how can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

As already said, this uncertainty is inherent in floating point numbers, [javascript only supports floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703725/integers-in-javascript) not integers. But if your rounding error is in the region 1957.3000000000001 and the most precise calculations you care about are in the region of 1957.0004 then you can get away with millions of calculations before you have to worry about the rounding error significantly affecting your results.