# JSON stringify conversion of float to int

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using Node.js and the built-in JSON object to stringify a JSON object. In the object is

```
{ 
    weight : 1.0
}
```

However when I stringify and write to a file the output is weight : 1.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is. `1` and `1.0` are the same thing in JavaScript.

Comment: use `parseInt(obj.weight)`

Comment: Try with 1.5 and you'll see it infact keeps the decimals..

Comment: The comment is the file generated is being used as an input for another system (Java) that cannot parse ints to double. Therefore the output format is required to be in 1.0

Comment: @kyleED How do you generate the JSON ...?? If you can enclose the values in double quotes or else no other way ....

Comment: It actually produces the "1.0" as you correctly identified. However the Java tool used now throws "String cannot be cast to Double".... good ole Java :) and I have no control over the source of the Java Tool.

Comment: @kyleED Parse it into a float before reading in the Java tool

Comment: @PrasathK required an extra processing step. But worked, thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually yours is not an issue , `1 == 1.0 == 1.00` in Javascript and if you have a float value like `1.55` then stringify gives you the same `1.55 not 1`.. Even then if you want `1.0` to be written , change the value into string

I mean Enclose the value in double quotes

```
{ 
    weight : "1.0"
}
```

Comment: This still is an issue if the JSON file is intended for code written in a different language which distinguishes between "1.0" and "1".

Comment: Actually this can be an issue. E.g. we have a json schema generator, which uses data from javascript client. The problem is that for 1.0 generator creates type "number", but for 1 it creates "integer". Then when data changes e.g. to 1.2 you validate 1.2 against integer...which fails.

Answer (score 4):

As noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4703752/98187) to a similar question, and on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7wkd9z69%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

> There is no such thing as an integer in JavaScript.  Numbers in JavaScript are "double-precision 64-bit format IEEE 754 values".

Open up your web browser's console and type `1.0`.  You'll see `1` printed out.  All numbers in JavaScript are floating point numbers, so your serializer simply chose to leave off unnecessary precision.

Comment: but when I write, `JSON.stringify(0.1)`, why does it print `0.1` and not `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`? it left off necessary precision

Comment: That number can't be represented as a 64-bit floating point number.  In general floating point numbers are bad at representing numbers that can't easily be written in the form 3.14159... * 2^n where "..." represents few digits and n is not enormous.