# Why javascript don't have a random function to generate integers?

Tags: javascript, random

I'm using this function to generate random int values :

```
var r = function(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};
```

It works perfectly but makes me wonder ... why there is no randomInt and randomFloat in javascript?

Comment: Because javascript is far from being perfect.

Comment: replace `return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min` with `return Math.ceil(Math.random() * (max - min )) + min`

Comment: There is no good answer to *why*, that's just the way the language is. As you know, it provides a random method, which can be used to generate random integers as you did.

Comment: @bfavaretto then the answer is, there is no good reason javascript just sucks, because it only has `number`s.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight I have to disagree with that. If js sucks (and I don't think it does), it wouldn't be for the lack of an Integer type or a randomInt method.

Comment: @bfavaretto yes we do all know it has the bad parts, (scopes) and the fact that everything is a `number`, also has some downsides.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight, you think JavaScript's functional scope is a *bad* part of the language? I quite like scope in JS.

Comment: @zzzzBov no i lied i dont `think JavaScript's functional scope is a bad part of the language` hehe i tricked you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JavaScript has a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FNumber) type which is a 64-bit float; there is no `Integer` type per se. `Math.random` by itself gives you a random `Number`, which is already a 64-bit float. I don't see why there couldn't be a `Math.randomInt` (internally it could either truncate, floor, or ceil the value). There is no good answer as to *why* the language doesn't have it; you would have to ask [Brendan Eich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich). However, you can emulate what you want using `Math.ceil` or `Math.floor`. This will give you back a **whole number**, which isn't really an `Integer` typewise, but is still a `Number` type.

Comment: +1, for being the only correct answer... :)

Comment: you may want to wikify this post.

Answer (score 2):

Because Javascript doesn't have those types. Pure javascript only has a generic `number` type.

More info on Javascript types may be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/7wkd9z69(v=vs.94).aspx) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals).

You may also want to look into this question: [Integers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703725/integers-in-javascript)

The marked answer says, and I quote:

> There are really only a few data types in Javascript: Objects, numbers, and strings. As you read, JS numbers are all 64-bit floats. There are no ints.

Comment: integer isn't just a type, it's a value as well.

Comment: [obligatory w3fools reference](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: i proposed an edit to replace this by a link on MDN

Comment: @zzzzBov, It's not the link, it's just not true there are not integers in javascript, because if so, there aren't strings as well. `"foo"` is a string and `2` is an integer. and `2.1` is a double or something like it.

Comment: Ok, I'm linking MSDN and MDN now.

Comment: Thanks guys for helping me make a better answer. I agree, linking to w3schools was a bad thing to do.

Comment: @gdoron, I wasn't directing my comment to you.

Comment: @gdoron `2` is an integer, but it is also a rational and a real number. This discussion will eventually enter a semanthic labyrinth.